# Firing an event on fixed intervals

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I have a scenario where I want to track if my Console application is alive or dead (due to exceptions etc..).

While the console application is performing its processing I want to have a mechanism where it has a timer which keeps on calling a reporting method after every N minutes, this method being called updates a time stamp in the DB.

So :

```
1 - Console application starts 
2 - Reports time stamp
3 - Keeps on doing its task (while in parallel it reports again after N seconds)
```

I know I can spawn a thread and make it sleep and wake up again after the "N" minutes but how reliable is that since threads might not fire until resources are free and the "N" minutes might not be valid anymore since the thread will fire on its own time.

How can I make sure the reporting is done in parallel while the processing is going on?

Comment: You have the right idea, you just need to make sure that N is noticeably less than whatever checks it.  For instance, update the database every minute, but only check it every 5 minutes, and any timestamp in the last 5 minutes is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than create your own thread use a built in Timer:

```
    private DateTime startTime;
    private System.Threading.Timer theTimer;
```

Start the timer:

```
            this.startTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimerCallback callback = TimerTick;
            this.theTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000);
```

The callback method:

```
    void TimerTick(object stateInfo)
    {
        TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
        // Do your stuff here.
    }
```

This creates a timer with no delay that fires every second.

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx)

The first integer is the `dueTime` amount of time to delay before the *callback* method is invoked. Specifying zero starts the timer immediately.

The second integer is the `period` - i.e. the time interval between invocations of the *callback* mathod.

You need to either make sure that your processing in `TimerTick` takes less than the period you have specified or ensure that it it re-entrant - i.e it can cope with being called before the previous invocation has completed. How you do that - or indeed whether you can do that - depends on your application.